# How to maintain same datatables in different environment (develop, test, production)?

Tags: java, database, spring

As a Developer if i make any changes in my development DB, I have to copy the script and execute it manually on the 2 DBs used for test and production.
Is there some way we can automate it ?
I am using java, mysql and spring mvc.
We are not allowed to make any changes on production DB

Comment: I can only guess why you were downvoted, SO revolves around helping people with coding problems and your question seems to be primarily asking for a deployment opinion. This question, imo, might be more relevant on server fault or super user.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature commonly called "database migration"; it's baked into some development frameworks (e.g. Ruby on Rails), but afaik not into Spring MVC.

The easiest thing is to use a [tool integrated into your build and deploy scripts](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/db-migrations-in-a-spring-project) - [Flyway](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-flyway-database-migration-example/) is popular.

The principle is this: you put your database changes into scripts, with a naming convention which indicates the order in which they are to be executed, and then run those scripts against the environment you're trying to update. Each database knows which was the last migration script to run, so you can pick up where you left off.

For instance:

```
filename: 201912130980-create-table-users.sql

create table users (
id int not null, 
name string not null,
age int not null);
```

Once you run this, it will create a new table for your users.

```
filename: 201912130981-add-title-to-users.sql

alter table users add title varchar null;
```

This adds an extra column to the table.

If you run these two in sequence, they will create your database from scratch. If you have run the "create" script on test, but not yet the "alter" script, next time you run the migrations on test, it will know not to re-run the create script, and pick up with the alter script.

In a comment, you said you're not allowed to execute table changes on production - I assume you mean that it requires some human process (e.g. asking a DBA). In this case, you've got a bit of a problem, because the "migration" process requires maintaining which is the last change that happened to the database, and that's guaranteed by the tooling. Humans tend to make mistakes...Flyway does this via [migration history tables.](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#schema-history-table)

The best option would be to work with your ops/dba team to see if you can deploy directly to production using Flyway. If that's too hard, you could create a "pre-prod" database and use that as the mirror of production; apply your migrations to that environment, and then send the migrations to the owners of production. You *may* be able to automate that via Jenkins or whatever you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the reply ,i tried integrating flyway Db into java before. But we are not allowed to execute any table changes on production Db. 
So just for production Db we execute it manually?

Comment: You should probably include "we're not allowed to execute table changes on production" in your question - it seems relevant...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this programatically using liquibase

You can refer here [liquibase example](https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app)

Comment: One of the features that Liquibase has is a command `updateSQL` that is designed for the issue OP mentions where DBAs won't allow changes in production. It generates the SQL that the DBAs can review, including updating the schema tracking table.